# hook_user_insert not working

Tags: users, hooks

I am new to drupal.
When user register into my website I need to get the users details and passed to a thirty for server .
I am trying the following hook,

```
function compass_preprocess_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  db_insert('test')
    ->fields(array(
      'accountid' => $account->uid,
    ))
    ->execute();
}
```

here compass-my theme name
Please help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hook_user_insert()` can only be implemented in a module, not a theme. Themes are just for styling/marking up content that modules produce, they shouldn't contain advanced logic like that.

You'll need to add a custom module and implement the hook in there to continue.

Comment: Thank you for the reply ..let me try it !!! so if i create a module like custom then i need to call hook as custom_user_insert()...is that correct?

Comment: exactly - whatever the machine name of your module is, that's the prefix for the hook. So if the module's .info file is "foo.module", your hook names will be prefixed by `foo_`

Comment: Its working!!!!